# HTML5 custom data attribute invisible or uneditable

Tags: jquery, html

How can I make HTML5 data attributes `data-dbclientid="7"` invisible or uneditable. I have done getting the attribute value part. I should be able to post this value from jQuery even if it is disabled or uneditable.

Comment: Every HTML content in the front-end can be editable thanks to dev' tools (such as Firebug or other).

Comment: Ya but anyway i can make it uneditable form jquery, so user cantt manipulate the value that has been posted?

Comment: You can't. If you send it, they have it. I have a feeling that what you are trying to accomplish should be done server side using the Session Object, not client side.

Comment: Yes, i could do that aswell. Rt now i have verified the posted data attribute with the $_GET[id] of another page. Thanks